# How the author proves that this function is smooth on the boundary $\partial W$?

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

I'm reading a proof of **Lemma 8.2.** from [this](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasgak/manifolds/notes5.pdf) lecture note.

---

> **Lemma 8.3.** Let $M$ be an $m$-manifold, $W$ an open set in $M$, and $f: W \to \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function. Suppose that $x \in W$. Then there is a smooth function $g: M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which agrees with $f$ on some neighbourhood of $x$ in $W$.

**Proof.** We need the following result, i.e.,

> [Lemma 8.2.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614802/there-is-a-smooth-function-theta-m-to0-1-such-that-theta-0-on-m-set) There is a smooth function $\theta: M \longrightarrow[0,1]$ such that $\theta =0$ on $M \setminus W$ and that $\theta = 1$ on some neighbourhood of $x$.

Let $\theta: M \longrightarrow[0,1]$ be the function given by **Lemma 8.2**, and set $g(y)=f(y) \theta(x)$ for $y \in W$ and $g(y)=0$ for $x \notin W$. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

---

**My understanding** If $y \in W$ then $g$ is smooth at $y$ by chain rule. Now let $y \notin W$. If $y \in M \setminus \overline W$, then $g$ is smooth at $y$ because there is some neighborhood $O$ of $y$ in $M \setminus \overline W$ such that $\theta = 0$ on $O$.

> Could you explain how to prove that $g$ is smooth at $y \in \partial W$?

Comment: Substantial text overlap with [this very recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614885/there-is-a-smooth-function-g-m-longrightarrow-mathbbr-which-agrees-with). Is it an extraordinary coincidence?

Comment: @Didier I have just come across that question. I can understand the proof in that thread, but not the one in the lecture note...

Comment: Right, I see. For the proof: smoothness is local. Either $g$ is identically zero in a neighbourhood of $y$ and therefore is smooth at $y$, or is a product of two smooth functions ($f$ and $\theta$) at $y$, and therefore is smooth at $y$

Comment: @Didier If $y \in \partial W$ then $y$ is not defined for $f$. Could you elaborate on this point?

Comment: $\theta$ is identically $0$ in a neighbourhood of $\partial W$, since $\theta$ has compact support in $W$. Therefore, for $y\in \partial W$, we are in the first case. This is an omnipresent trick in differential geometry

Comment: After reading carefully the linked notes, the author never says that $\theta$ has compact support in $W$, and therefore, their proof is not valid: this could be the case that $f$ blows up faster than $\theta$ crashes at $\partial W$, resulting in $\theta\times f$ being undefined there. However, you can fix the argument by taking $\theta$ with compact support (same proof as that of lemma 8.2 with $W'\subset W$ precompact in $W$).

Comment: @Didier This is exactly where I got confused. Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original author makes a little mistake in their argument: they never require for $\theta$ to have compact support in $W$.
Therefore, $\theta f$ could be undefined on $\partial W$, for instance, if $f$ blows up faster than $\theta$ crashes there.
However, this is not a big mistake and this can be fixed easily, by taking $\theta$ with compact support in $W$ (same proof than that of lemma 8.2, replacing $W$ with $W'\subset W$ precompact).